# Clean duplicates in a list field inside an array of objects in each document

Tags: arrays, database, mongodb, mongodb-query, nosql

```
{ 
    "_id" : "1235", 
    "details" : [
        {           
            "productId" : "PRODUCT1",           
            "myList" : [
                "0001", 
                "0001", 
                "0002", 
                "0002", 
                
            ]
         },
         {           
            "productId" : "PRODUCT2",            
            "myList" : [
                "0002", 
                "0002", 
                "1234", 
                "1234", 
                
            ]
         }
    ]
}
```

I have myList in each nested sub-document. I need to clear duplicates in myList in each document. Any query to accomplish this?

In the output, the values in myList should be a union.

This is the expected output. Notice that myList doesn't contain duplicates anymore.

```
{
  "_id" : "1235", 
  "details" : [
       {       
          "productId" : "PRODUCT1",           
          "myList" : [       
              "0001", 
              "0002", 
          ]
       },
       {  
          "productId" : "PRODUCT2",            
          "myList" : [
              "0002",      
              "1234", 
          ]
       }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Can you show what's the expected result?

Comment: Updated the details. @mickl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need [$map](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/index.html) to replace existing array and you can use [$setUnion](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setUnion/index.html) to get rid of duplicated entries:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $addFields: {
            details: {
                $map: {
                    input: "$details",
                    in: {
                        $mergeObjects: [
                            "$$this",
                            { myList: { $setUnion: "$$this.myList" } }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    { $out: "collection" }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/MX742nmO3cF)

Comment: This worked - thanks. How do I update the collection using this aggregation?

Comment: @balkotdude try `$out`: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/

Answer (score 0):

Try Converting the List into a Set. Set will eliminate duplicates. then convert back set into a List.

Answer (score 0):

Using `$setUnion` in array `details.myList`,

- `$unwind` details because its array
- `$group` by _id for group separate documents of details and `$setUnion` and push it to again details

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $unwind: "$details"
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id",
      details: {
        $push: {
          productId: "$details.productId",
          myList: {
            $setUnion: "$details.myList"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Working Playground: https://mongoplayground.net/p/kJQ5VHxepuy